# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{n+2(-1)^nn^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Show whether the following series converges or not: $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{n+2(-1)^nn^2}$$

I've tried everything I could come up with, for example root test, direct comparison test, testing whether the series converges absolutely etc., nothing yielding a result. A similar problem is [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/646610/determine-if-sum-n-1-infty-frac-1nn2nn31-converges-or-diverge) but the problem is that denominator and numerator are switched in my case.

Comment: Have you tried limit comparison? Factor $n$ from numerator and denominator to see what series you might compare with.

Comment: There is an obvious cancellation by $n$. Are you sure that's the correct series?

Comment: Yes, there is a cancellation by $n$ but how can I proceed from there?

Comment: @user I was just checking you copied the problem correctly. It's a bit unusual for problems to be stated with such obvious simplifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be written as an alternating series:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{2n + (-1)^n}.
$$
Since $1/(2n+(-1)^n)$ is nonincreasing and has limit 0, the series converges by the [alternating series test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test).

One can also rather easily find the sum of the series. We have
\begin{multline}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{2n + (-1)^n} = -1 + \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{2n + (-1)^n} = -1 + \sum_{m=1}^\infty \left[\frac{1}{2(2m) + 1} - \frac{1}{2(2m+1)-1}\right] \\ = -1 + \sum_{m=1}^\infty \left[\frac{1}{4m+1} - \frac{1}{4m+1}\right] = -1 + \sum_{m=1}^\infty 0 = -1
\end{multline}

Comment: thank you but how do we rewrite this?

Comment: @user divide top and bottom by $(-1)^n n$.

Answer (score 0):

Multiply the numerator and denominator by $n-2(-1)^nn^2$: $$\dfrac{n^2-2(-1)^nn^3}{n^2-4n^4}=\dfrac{1-2n(-1)^n}{1-4n^2}=\frac{1}{1-4n^2}-(-1)^n\frac{2n}{1-4n^2}.$$
Series from both members are converge. First absolutely, second -- conditionally. Therefore, the entire series converges only conditionally.

Comment: Thanks but how do you get that the second series converges conditionally?

Comment: by Leibniz's test

Comment: but for that you have to show that $\frac{2n}{1-4n^2}$ is monotonically decreasing, I haven't been able to do that so far

Comment: the simplest thing is to find the derivative of function $\frac{2x}{4x^2-1}$ (it needs to change a sign for Leibniz, of course)

Comment: don't we have to find the derivative of $\frac{2n}{1-4n^2}$ which is $\frac{2+8n^2}{1-8n^2+16n^4}$ and doesn't really tell us much

Comment: you need to change a sign for Leibniz, and the derivative will become negative